# What is the meaning of 'artificial'?

Tags: meaning

I have just been munching on a bag of potato crisps  (American: chips). (Well it is nearing Christmas and any thoughts of weight control are abandoned for the duration.)

They are very nice, an up-market brand and the label makes great play of the fact that they contain ***nothing artificial***.

The actual ingredients are listed as: Select potatoes, sunflower oil, sea salt and balsamic vinegar, potato maltodextrin, sugar, dried barley malt vinegar, citric acid.

Now, I will take their word for it that none of those things are ***artificial***.

My dictionary defines ***artificial*** as *made or produced by human beings rather than occurring naturally, especially as a copy of something natural*.

So what might these crisps contain were they to have some ***artificial*** ingredient?  Indeed if ***artificial*** means something that doesn't occur naturally, then wouldn't it have to be imported from another planet in order to be deemed *artificial*. Even something created by humankind presumably ultimately has to be composed of things occurring naturally.

So to summarise ***What artificial substance might one expect to find*** in a bag of crisps? And ***What does artificial actually mean, in scientific terms, anyway***?

The bag also says that the potatoes are ***hand cooked***. I wonder what that means?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if I had to guess I'd say it might be because this question concerns itself with food industry labelling regulations more than the English Language.  Or that you asked 2 questions. ;)

Comment: Colourings and flavourings can both be artificial (that is, synthesised). But "What artificial substance might one expect to find in a bag of crisps" is not a question about English; it's food science. "What does artificial mean" you have already answered. That only leaves "hand cooked", which at least superficially and in the absence of research is answered by General Reference. (And "I wonder" is not a question)

Comment: @DigitalChris I can't be bothered to think about why they may have down voted, if they haven't got the self confidence to say. But as regards your point, this is not strictly to do with labelling. The label states the actual ingredients, as it has to do by law. But in addition, in much larger lettering, it declare ***nothing artificial***.

Comment: OK. This is a question about food science.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about food science.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hold on. You've covered a lot of ground there. Let's first consider the 'hand cooked' point. I do know what the words 'hand' and 'cooked' mean. And that is the part that is General Reference. But when someone declares something 'hand cooked' what are they actually saying? Did someone stand in front of a stove with a frying pan and cook the potatoes? We see this kind of thing all the time - home made- untouched by human hand - etc. Can we, as English language specialists, safely declare that the terms are meaningless?

Comment: @AndrewLeach As regards your other points, yes I know what the dictionary says *artificial* means. But both Josh 61, and Centaurus supply definitions which they think are applied in the food industry. And those definitions are less restrictive than Oxford Dictionaries (where, if you followed the logic precisely, you could never have anything artificial). So who is the final arbiter of 'artificial' and in what document is it contained. We all know that the EU regulations on food additives differ and are usually more restrictive than the American ones e.g the big battle over hormones in beef.

Comment: @WS2 That's food science. Your own definition of *artificial* includes "a copy of something natural". If you rework the question so it's a **question on the Use of English,** I'll reverse my action. Or, of course, you and others in the community may vote to do so.

Comment: @AndrewLeach If I just raise a question 'What are we to understand by the term 'artificial'?, would that suffice?

Comment: Yes, but you would need to demonstrate that the dictionary definition of "something that is not natural, or which is a copy of something natural" is insufficient.

Comment: This question might be interesting on Marketing.SE or Nutrition.SE, if such places existed. Labelers frequently use catch phrases to make products appear more healthy than they really are, with words like: _100% Natural, No Artificial Ingredients, Contains Real Fruit, No Trans Fats, Sugar Free, No Added Sugars, Whole Grain,_ etc. More often than not, "Reduced Sugar" means "Sweetened with Artificial Sweeteners." Interesting to discuss, but only marginally related to English. In this context, the words mean what regulators allow them to mean; dictionary definitions have little impact.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19608/discussion-on-question-by-ws2-what-is-the-meaning-of-artificial).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have realised overnight the important point about ***artificial***. It has to be used as an adjective. You can have an artificial something. For example an 'artificial fibre' is such as nylon or polyester, since they do not naturally occur as fibres like wool or cotton. You can have 'artificial leather', but you cannot just simply say something is 'artificial'. Because in the world everything starts in some natural format. So a label saying 'nothing artificial contained here' is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

I think that  [artificial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Artificial) regarding edible  products is used with the meaning:

> - not arising from natural growth or characterized by vital processes.
> - **inorganic**-  lacking the properties characteristic of living organisms.

Any artificial substance would  have been produced by a chemical process; artificial flavouring or preservatives for instance.

As for the 'hand cooked', the definition, it suggests  a process of cooking which is more 'home made' rather than industrialised. This looks like a marketing expedient to add to the non artificial qualities of the product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in food processing technology but I understand as "artificial" any compound which is synthesized in laboratories and added to food, such as the following, from [Medline Plus](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/002435.htm)

> •Antioxidants in oily or fatty foods
>
> •Artificial sweeteners, such as aspartame, saccharine, and sodium cyclamate
>
> •Benzoic acid in fruit juices
>
> •Lecithin, gelatins, corn starch, waxes, gums, and propylene glycol in food stabilizers and emulsifiers
>
> •Many different dyes and coloring substances
>
> •Monosodium glutamate (MSG)
>
> •Nitrates and nitrites in hot dogs and other meat products
>
> •Sulfites in beer, wine, and packaged vegetables

Comment: I did look up Monosodium glutamate (MSG) and found, in the opening paragraph in Wikipedia, that it is naturally occurring in tomatoes, Parmesan, potatoes and mushrooms. So I am not at all clear why it is classified as *artificial*.

Comment: @WS2 I think it can be considered artificial because it has to be extracted with chemicals in laboratories. Not sure, though.